# Add css style after element loads in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a function that is used to calculate the left margin which will be assigned to list elements. The issue is that the id for the list element is generated when the page loads and has a binding to it:

```
<li *ngFor "let msg in messages; let i in index;" id="#messages-{{i}}"> ... </li>
```

How can I use my function to assign the margin to these list contents? Every li element will have different margins.

Comment: Can you provide more context for what you're trying to do? There might be a better way. Also, why are you using a hash in the `id` attribute?

Comment: @Phix I am trying to add left margin that will vary for each list element from a javascript function. So every list element will have a different left margin when they are loaded on the webpage. The hash is just for my own purposes, I can remove it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML Template

```
<li *ngFor "let msg in messages; let i in index;" 
[style.marginTop.px]="getMarginLeft(msg)" id="#messages-{{i}}"> ... </li>
```

In your Ts file

```
  getMarginLeft(msg) {
    return msg.length;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this helped!

Comment: @shasha if this is  what you ask for can you mark my answer as a correct answer.